# How do I get city with highest population in SQL Server (Express Edition)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm using SQL Server with two columns named City and Population. How do I find the name of the city with the highest population (in syntax)? I've heard SQL Server is a little bit different from MySQL.

Current Code:

```
Select MAX(Population) from City
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the code is pretty similar between T-SQL and MySQL.

There are other approaches that would work, but this might be the easiest to understand based on the code you've already written.

```
select
  city,
  population
from
  city
where
  population = (
    select max(population) from city
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `max(population) over (order by population desc)` syntax (do not neglect to alias (here by `q`) inner query in SQL Server):

```
SELECT city
FROM
    (SELECT MAX(population) OVER (ORDER BY population desc) max_pop, *
     FROM city) q
WHERE population = q.max_pop;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/52f76/1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the maximum population in a subquery and then find all cities with that population:

```
select city
  from my_table
  where population = (
    select max(population) from my_table
  )
```

This query will also give you multiple cities, in the (rare) case where two cities share the maximum population.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the records by Population in descending order and then pick out the first record only:

```
SELECT TOP 1 City FROM t
ORDER BY Population DESC
```

Comment: Oh, and if you want all cities with the same maximum population to be shown, use TOP 1 WITH TIES ...